# Highcharts server side export Pie With Data Labels (phantomjs)

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to export a Pie chart with data labels. I'm using the Phantomjs server side export functionality. I get the chart image back correctly but the datalabels don't show up. The sample data structure in the web version adds the data labels as expected.

Is there specific configuration requited to get the data labels to show up?
I'm on HIghcharts 4.0.1

The JSON I'm sending over to the phantom server is:

```
{"infile":"{ legend: {enabled: false},chart: {borderWidth: 0},colors: ['#4572A7', '#AA4643', '#89A54E', '#80699B', '#3D96AE', '#DB843D', '#92A8CD', '#A47D7C', '#B5CA92'],credits: {text:'CannLabs'},title: {text: 'Potency results'},plotOptions: {pie: {dataLabels: {enabled: true,color: 'black',format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'}}},series: [{type: 'pie',name: 'Potency Results',data: [{name: 'CBD-V', y: 0.00},{name:'CBD-A',y: 0.00},{name:'CBG',y: 0.00},{name:'CBD',y: 0.01},{name:'THC-V',y: 0.00},{name:'CBN',y: 0.01},{name:'THC',y: 0.87},{name:'CBC',y: 0.02},{name:'THC-A',y: 0.00}]}]};"}
```

Comment: Try to disable  [defer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.defer) option.

Comment: Disabling defer didn't cause the labels to show up in the export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the 4.0.1 version of highcharts. I upgraded to the master version of the highcharts.js file and the labels are now rendered correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If the accepted answer above doesn't help you, try adding `animation: false` to your series configuration, like so:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false
    }
},
```

Comment: Had a problem with pie charts not rendering correctly to pdf in phantomjs. Switching off animation did the trick. Thanks.